# Received Policy Notification: Apple Music API/MusicKit requirements

Tags: ios, apple-music, apple-musickit

I received a message from Apple for many of my iOS apps. It says I use Apple Music in connection with advertising and they give me one week to resolve it. I do not use it maybe one of advertising libraries do but I have no idea how to check it. What they really want me to do. Any idea?

> We are writing to let you know about new information regarding your app.
>
> Upon re-evaluation, we found that your app is not in compliance with
> the App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically, we found:
>
> Guideline 4.5.2 - Design - Apple Sites and Services
>
> Your app appears to be using Apple Music in connection with advertising.
>
> To resolve this issue, ensure that Apple Music user data is not used for advertising purposes. If your app is not intended to use Apple Music, it would be appropriate to remove the Apple Music APIs from your app.
>
> To ensure there is no interruption of the availability of your app on the App Store, please submit an update within one week of the date of this message. If we do not receive an update within one week, your app may be removed from sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to access the Music Library in your app remove **NSAppleMusicUsageDescription** key from the **info.plist**

It turns out I got this policy violations for Apps that don't use any music functionality and it has something to do with **NSAppleMusicUsageDescription** key in the **info.plist**

From iOS 10 Apple requires a description for Music Library access.
**AdMob** used Apple Music library and as a workaround NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with the description "**Advertisement would like to use music library.**" was needed to be added to the info.plist.

It is not required anymore, I assume AdMob does not use the Music Library anymore. 
I didn't remove that key from subsequent updates and I think that triggered the policy notification.

I removed the key in latest update to address this policy violation and it was approved without any issues.